# WCF Service Error

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service deployed on a windows 2003 server. We are using a WPF application to consume this service. The trouble is if we deploy a new version of WCF service or leave the IIS and WPF application idle for sometime and then try to execute a functionality, we are get the following exception:

```
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 119 bytes of the response were:'<HEAD><TITLE>500: Server Error [20-0004]</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>500: Server Error [20-0004]<H1>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error usually means there was an unhandled exception in the service. Look in the Windows event logs to see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a proxy / connection to the server, then leaving it open and using this proxy when needed.

There are two problems with this:

- The problem you are getting due to timeout in periods of inactivity.
- That the connection is maintained when it is not used reduces scalability.

A better way to do it is to create the proxy connection when you require it, then close / dispose of it after it gas been used. Normally I use the using statement for this.

Answer (score 0):

when you get below mentioned error

500: Server Error [20-0004]

This is siteminder Web Agent error, If your website is SSO protected, then it might have Siteminder ISAPI issue with initializing.

Check Event and SSO logs.

[Origin Blog](https://middlewarekb.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/500-server-error-20-0004/)